# Is the category of topologically free $k[[h]]$-modules locally presentable?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra, locally-presentable-categories

$\newcommand{\colim}{\operatorname{colim}}$
Let $k$ be a field (of characteristic 0, say) and $M$ be a module over $R=k[[h]]$. Recall that the $h$-adic completion of $M$ is
$$
\hat M:=\lim M/h^nM,
$$
and that $M$ is called complete and separated if the canonical map $M \rightarrow \hat M$ is an isomorphism. $M$ is called topologically free if it's of the form $M_0[[h]]$ for a $k$-vector space $M_0$. This is equivalent to $M$ being complete, separated and torsion free.

The category $R\text{-}mod^{tf}$ of topologically free $R$-modules is not abelian, which is why people advocate the use of the larger category of so-called [$L$-complete modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/L-complete+module) instead. This category *is* abelian, and moreover $\lambda$-locally presentable for all cardinals $\lambda > \aleph_0$. Turns out I really only care about the latter property, and for a while I thought the category of topologically free modules was however **not** locally presentable, but on second thought I'm not so sure!

Namely, I was convinced this category is not closed under colimits, but now I believe it is: let $T$ be the functor that takes an $R$-module to its $h$-adic completion and then mod out by torsion. Unless I'm missing something obvious the result is topologically free, and $T$ is left adjoint to the inclusion of topologically free $R$-modules into all $R$-modules. Hence $R\text{-}mod^{tf}$ is a reflective sub-category of $R\text{-}mod$, hence should be locally presentable. Explicitly, $\colim M_i$ should be computed in this category as $T$ of the $\colim M_i$ in $R\text{-}mod$, and $R$ itself is clearly a generator. Its is not small, however, but because $\lambda$-colimits commutes with $\lambda$-small limits $R$ is I think $\lambda$-compact for every $\lambda >\aleph_0$ (this is pretty much the argument that shows the analog fact for $L$-complete modules).

Am I missing something? Does anyone knows a reference where this is done carefully?

Comment: Small comment: your functor probably should divide by the *closure* of the torsion of the completion.

Comment: Fair point, or maybe I need to mod out by torsion first ?